# How to train PyTorch transfer learning tutorial with more then 1 GPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pytorch

I am currently following the PyTorch transfer learning tutorial in: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

I have been able to complete tutorial and train on both a CPU and 1 GPU.

I am utilising Google Cloud Platform Notebook Instances and using 4 NVIDIA Tesla k80 x 4 GPU. It is here that I run into a Server Connection Error (invalid response: 504) error when I train the network on more than 1 GPU

```py
model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

## Using 4 GPUs
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    model_ft = nn.DataParallel(model_ft)
model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=25)
```

The idea was to utilise the data parallelism function to utilise all available GPU (which is 4) to train the network.

Am I missing something in the implementation, please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it is easiest to use **Horovod** to do multi GPU training. Here is an example of a distributed training script with GPU using Horovod: https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/pytorch_mnist.py

You will need to have **OpenMPI** installed (likely already on the box), and you will need to have Horovod installed in the python enviroment (`pip install horovod` -- full install instructions are here https://github.com/horovod/horovod#install).

Then you would start your job with `horovodrun -np 4 python pytorch_mnist.py` (Here some docs on how to start a Horovod run: https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpirun.html)

This will enable you to train not only on one node with multiple GPUs, but also across multiple nodes (e.g. across 2 nodes with 4 GPUs each).

The salient points for distributed training with Horovod are:

- Horovod will start as many processes as you instruct it to, so in your case 4. Each process will run the same script that will only differ in the Horovod/MPI rank. The rank is then used to get the corresponding cuda device:

```
    # Horovod: pin GPU to local rank.
    torch.cuda.set_device(hvd.local_rank())
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.seed)
```

- A `DistributedSampler` is used to divide the data up across the different nodes. `hvd.rank()` is used to make sure different partitions of the data are used by each of the processes and `hvd.size()` captures how many processes there are in total.

```
    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
    train_dataset, num_replicas=hvd.size(), rank=hvd.rank())
```

- Wrap your optimizer with a `DistributedOptimizer` -- that will take care of aggregating the gradients across the processes at the end of each minibatch:

```
    # Horovod: wrap optimizer with DistributedOptimizer.
    optimizer = hvd.DistributedOptimizer(optimizer,
                                         named_parameters=model.named_parameters(),
                                         compression=compression)
```

- Most importantly, you don't have to modify your actual model and training loop, which is pretty neat.

There are a few more interesting things in the sample (e.g. growing the learning rate with the number or processes, broadcasting your parameters at the start).